# Given identity map $U:\ell^n_a\rightarrow \ell^n_b$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$, how to computer operator norm $\forall a,b$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $U:\ell^n_a\rightarrow \ell^n_b$ is the identity map of the underlying vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, then how do you compute the operator norm $U$ for all possible values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Does $\ell^n_a$ mean $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with the norm $\lVert x\rVert_a = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^a\right)^{1/a}$?

Comment: Assuming Daniel's guess is right – and I am sure it is – then note that the two norms agree for vectors where just one coordinate is non-zero. It seems reasonable to conjecture, then, that they differ the most where all the coordinates are equal. You can compute the ratio of the norms explicitly in that case. Then you need to work out if this really solves the problem or not. My bet is that it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing [I guessed right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547342/given-identity-map-u-elln-a-rightarrow-elln-b-for-mathbbrn-how-to-c#comment1165074_547342):

For $a \leqslant b$, we have $\lVert U\rVert = 1$. The standard basis vectors have $\lVert e_k\rVert_a = \lVert e_k\rVert_b = 1$, so $\lVert U\rVert \geqslant 1$. But if $\lVert x\rVert_a = 1$, then $\lvert x_k\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $k$, so

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^b \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^a = 1,$$

and $\lVert x\rVert_b \leqslant 1$, so $\lVert U\rVert \leqslant 1$.

For $b < a$, we have $\lVert U\rVert = n^{1/b-1/a}$. For the vector with all components $1$, we have $\lVert \mathbb{1}\rVert_a = n^{1/a}$, so that shows $\lVert U\rVert \geqslant n^{1/b-1/a}$. On the other hand, by Hölder's inequality,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^b \leqslant \left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1^{a/(a-b)}\right)^{(a-b)/a}\cdot \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^a\right)^{b/a},$$

so $\lVert x\rVert_b \leqslant n^{1/b-1/a}\lVert x\rVert_a$.

Comment: yes, that does it - many thanks!